# Inserting EPS file into a word document without converting it to wmf

Tags: microsoft-word

I came across a word document (docx) with an EPS file embedded in it. When I examined the archive, I noticed that the eps file is within the media section of the word file:

[image]

I tried to create a similar file by doing **Insert > Picture > my.eps**. When I do this, my EPS image immediately gets converted into a .wmf file:

[image]

Does anyone know if these is a way to insert an EPS image without converting it into a .wmf file?